# How to access an array of reviews inside a JSON object using JSON Server in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, frontend

I have a JSON object that contains an array of reviews for a product, and I'm trying to access only the reviews part of the object using JSON Server. I tried making a GET request to `http://localhost:3000/products/1/reviews` (where 1 is the ID of the product), but I'm getting a 404 error.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Product A",
  "description": "This is a great product.",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "I really like this product."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "rating": 5,
      "comment": "This product exceeded my expectations!"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "rating": 3,
      "comment": "This product is okay, but I've had better."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This seems like a back-end problem, not front-end.

Comment: i am stuck and i dont know where to begin...i even have made a routes.json file but i still get the error...here is the routes.json file...{
  "/products/:id/reviews": "/products/:id/reviews"
}

Comment: I think that the problem is in the backend as the endpoint may not be exist that's why it returns 404.

Comment: Check if the url works in a browser?

Comment: I think you don't understand how requests work - does `http://localhost:3000/products/1` work?

Comment: Yeah...http://localhost:3000/products/1..is working but http://localhost:3000/products/1/reviews isnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long the url `http://localhost:3000/products/1/reviews` shows nothing in your browser, it's a backend problem and has nothing to do with frontend (Vue).

Check and fix your backend API till it responds you with the data you showed.